# Haskell: How to get rid of doubled or tripled elements in a list

Tags: haskell

Objective: Finding the permutation of a list such as ["abc", "bc", "acc"]

Problem: My permutation contains doubled and tripled elements and I want to get rid of those elements.

The result that I obtained from the list above is :

[["abc","bc","acc"],["abc","bc"],["abc","acc","bc"],["abc","acc"],["abc","acc"],["abc"],["bc","abc","acc"],["bc","abc"],["bc","acc","abc"],["bc","acc"],["bc","acc"],["bc"],["acc","abc","bc"],["acc","abc"],["acc","bc","abc"],["acc","bc"],**["acc","bc"]**,["acc"],["bc","acc"],["bc"],**["acc","bc"]**,["acc"],["acc"],[]]

The code that I wrote in order to get rid of those doubled elements is stated below:

```
fct [] = []
fct (xs)
    | (head xs) `elem` xs = fct (delete (head xs) xs)
    | otherwise = fct xs
```

Here I wanted to take the first element of the list and compare it with the rest of the list. 
Can you help me to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: See the `nub` function in Prelude.  If it's too slow then find Bart's `nubOrd` and perhaps finish what he started in getting that put into base.

Comment: Rather than generating extra entries and then deleting them, why not just generate only the ones you want?

Comment: @drysdam
I could not find another solution for permutation thus I work on deleting duplications.

@TomMd
nub function worked perfectly.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Given a list [a,b,c] is this what you would like to obtain? `[[],
[a],
[b],
[c],
[a,b],
[a,c],
[b,a],
[b,c],
[c,a],
[c,b],
[a,b,c],
[a,c,b],
[b,a,c],
[b,c,a],
[c,a,b],
[c,b,a]]`

Answer (score 2):

Those are not permutations, because some of them don't contain all the original elements.  It seems to be a combination of permutations and selections.

In ghci:

```
Prelude Data.List Control.Monad> concatMap permutations $ filterM (const [False, True])["abc", "bc", "acc"]
[[],["acc"],["bc"],["bc","acc"],["acc","bc"],["abc"],["abc","acc"],["acc","abc"], ["abc","bc"],["bc","abc"],["abc","bc","acc"],["bc","abc","acc"],["acc","bc","abc"],["bc","acc","abc"],["acc","abc","bc"],["abc","acc","bc"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [nub](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3anub) to remove duplicates from a list.